# No me encuentra la clase que quiero usar y estoy utilizando bien los namespace

Tags: php

Utilice el vender para q me genere un namespace base y coloco todo bien pero no me encuentra la clase no se como hacer.

El mensaje de error es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Portafolio\model\Contacto" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PORTAFOLIO\src\main.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PORTAFOLIO\src\main.php on line 12

La línea afectada es ésta:

```
<?php
    use Portafolio\model\Contacto;


    if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : 'Nombre de 
    prueba';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : 'email de prueba';
    $tema = isset($_POST['tema']) ? $_POST['tema'] : '...';
    $mensaje = isset($_POST['mensaje']) ? $_POST['mensaje'] : '...';

    (aqui)    $contacto = new Contacto($nombre, $email, $tema, $mensaje);

    $contacto->save();

    }
    ?>
```

Y este es el namespace que me genera el composer para los archivos src:

```
{
    "name": "portafolio/web",
    "description": "n",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Portafolio\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Esteban russo",
            "email": "oerusso28@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar cómo tienes tu carpeta `src`? ¿Acaso tienes la clase `Contacto` en esta ruta: `src/model`? Si es así, sería mejor definir en el `psr-4` una nueva ruta con algo como esto: `"Model\\": "src/model/"` y podrás escribir los `use` de este modo: `use \Model\Contacto;`

Comment: Si, el archivo contacto esta en src/model/contacto. Pero en tal caso como dices seria Model/model/contacto, pq el Model del vendor va hacer referencia a la carpeta src y el model a la carpeta model dentro de src. No me permite pasar captura del directorio,sino te la pasaba. Pero cual seria el inconveniente con ese nombre de namespace q tengo actualmente? q no condice con el nombre de la carpeta?